# Does OPENJDK supports to develop EJB and to deploy in WildFly server?

Tags: java, jboss, migration, ejb

I have a Web Application which is running on Oracle JDK 1.6 & jboss-5.1.0.GA application server.
this Application contains EJBs.
while i'm trying to compile my code with **OpenJDK** i'm facing issues with ***javax.rmi.**** packages.
is it possible to migrate my Application to OpenJDK latest version?
please anyone suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of OpenJDK as of now is OpenJDK 14. If you are planning to migrate your application straight away from version 6 to version 14, let me tell you upfront that there will be a lot of issues. A lot of packages were deprecated and removed in jdk 11, which includes CORBA related javax.rmi* packages and some other Java EE packages.See [JEP320](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320#:%7E:text=In%20Java%20SE%209%2C%20the,xml) for more details.

In a nutshell, if you decide to go ahead with the migration, be prepared to revamp the application both in code as well as application server level. I think you would have to probably check for the JBoss support for the jdk version that you wish to upgrade to.